# Using jQueryUI Dialog, how can I get the element that opened the dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

For example, I have many rows of data, each with an "edit" button with a class "edit-button".

I have a `.live()` click handler on for `.edit-button` elements.

In a dialog callback for one of the "buttons", I would like to pass the row as an argument.

Specifically, I'd like to get the ID attribute of the `.edit-button`'s parent `tr` (in a table).

Usually, I might do something along the lines of:

```
var tr = $(element).parents("tr:first");
```

...to get the `tr` element.

How would this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding with `.live('click', function(eventObj)`

eventObj will give you access to the eventObj.target that you can use to determine which DOM element fired it.

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/live/ (look for "Multiple Events" *)
- http://api.jquery.com/bind/ (look for "The Event object")
- http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

* the example relates to using event to get .type, but you can also get .target from it.

Comment: And from my short example, `$(element)` would be `$(eventObj.target)`, if I'm remembering correctly. And despite my hopes to pass values around in a more direct way, the value does have to be set somewhere else (as German Rumm pointed out in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Store the element (`this` in the click handler) somewhere so you can access it later.
If you want the parent TR, use `var tr = $(this).closest('tr');`

Comment: It can be stored on a dialog itself: `$('#dialog').dialog().data('opener', this)` inside a click handler